# Mysql query, running slow when using ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, query-optimization

I have a query running slow, when using ORDER BY Clause.

Table with max rows, includes approx. 30.000 rows.

The result is 10 rows, and takes approx 0.2 seconds.

Without "ORDER BY id DESC" it takes 0.01 seconds.

I have looked into other posts on stack and tried optimizing this script, but my knowledge has reached its limits.

Also I have created index on all column joins, WHERE, ORDER by.

Do you see anything that can be improved, or an idea on how to make order by return faster results?

Mysql looks like this

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  posts.id, posts.createdDateTime, posts.caption, posts.postUrl,
                posts.isVideo, posts.paymentType, posts.postPrice, profile.name,
                profile.username, 
                ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM  likes
                    where  likes.postIdFK=posts.id
                ) as likes, 
                ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM  likes
                    where  likes.postIdFK=posts.id
                      AND  likes.userIdFK=21643
                ) as myLike, 
                ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM  comments
                    where  comments.postIdFK=posts.id
                      AND  comments.deleted=0
                ) as comments
            FROM  posts
            JOIN  users AS profile  ON posts.userIdFK=profile.id
            WHERE  posts.deleted=0
              AND  profile.deleted=0
              AND  ( posts.userIdFK IN (
                        SELECT  subscribedToProfileIdFK
                            FROM  
                                ( SELECT  userSubscriptions.subscribedToProfileIdFK, max(monthlySubscriptions.endSubscription) endSubscription
                                    FROM  userSubscriptions
                                    LEFT JOIN  monthlySubscriptions  ON monthlySubscriptions.userSubscriptionId=userSubscriptions.id
                                    WHERE  userSubscriptions.userIdFK=21643
                                      AND  userSubscriptions.quickpayComplete=1
                                    GROUP BY  userSubscriptions.id 
                          ) t
                            WHERE  (t.endSubscription >= CURDATE())
                            GROUP BY  t.subscribedToProfileIdFK )
                      OR  posts.id IN (
                        SELECT  paidPosts.postIdFK
                            FROM  paidPosts
                            WHERE  paidPosts.userIdFK=21643 
                          )
                      OR  posts.userIDFK=21643 ) 
        ) AS row
    ORDER BY  id DESC
    LIMIT  0,10
```

EXPLAIN looks like this

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | profile | ref | PRIMARY,deleted | deleted | 1 | const | 5410 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY | posts | ref | userIdFK,deleted | userIdFK | 4 | admin_slc.profile.id | 1 | Using where |
| 8 | MATERIALIZED | paidPosts | ALL | userIdFK,postIdFK | NULL | NULL | NULL | 5 | Using where |
| 6 | MATERIALIZED |  | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 14 | Using where |
| 7 | DERIVED | userSubscriptions | index | userIdFK, quickpayComplete | PRIMARY | 4 | NULL | 15 | Using where |
| 7 | DERIVED | monthlySubscriptions | ref | userSubscriptionId | userSubscriptionId | 4 | admin_slc.userSubscriptions.id | 1 |  |
| 5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | comments | ref | postIdFK,deleted | postIdFK | 4 | admin_slc.posts.id | 1 | Using where |
| 4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | likes | ref | userIdFK,postIdFK | postIdFK | 4 | admin_slc.posts.id | 1 | Using where |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | likes | ref | postIdFK | postIdFK | 4 | admin_slc.posts.id | 1 | Using index |

If you need table definitions, let me know.

// Thx

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE likes;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely rewrite this query to remove the select queries from SELECT clause as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT posts.id, 
           posts.createdDateTime,  
           posts.caption,  
           posts.postUrl,  
           posts.isVideo,  
           posts.paymentType,  
           posts.postPrice, 
           profile.name,  
           profile.username,
           l.cnt as likes,
           ml.cnt as myLike,
           comm.cnt as comments -- as comments
    FROM posts 
    JOIN users AS profile ON posts.userIdFK=profile.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT likes.postIdFK, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM likes group by likes.postIdFK) as l 
      on l.postIdFK=posts.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT likes.postIdFK, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM likes where likes.userIdFK=21643 group by likes.postIdFK) ml 
      on ml.postIdFK=posts.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT comments.postIdFK, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM comments where comments.deleted=0 group by comments.postIdFK) as comm 
       on comm.postIdFK=posts.id
    WHERE posts.deleted=0 
    AND profile.deleted=0
    AND ( posts.userIdFK IN (
            SELECT subscribedToProfileIdFK 
              FROM (SELECT userSubscriptions.subscribedToProfileIdFK,
                           max(monthlySubscriptions.endSubscription) endSubscription
                      FROM userSubscriptions 
                      LEFT JOIN monthlySubscriptions ON monthlySubscriptions.userSubscriptionId=userSubscriptions.id 
                     WHERE userSubscriptions.userIdFK=21643 
                       AND userSubscriptions.quickpayComplete=1
                     GROUP BY userSubscriptions.id) t
            WHERE (t.endSubscription >= CURDATE())
           -- GROUP BY t.subscribedToProfileIdFK -- this group by is not needed
           )
        OR exists 
           (SELECT 1 
              FROM paidPosts 
             WHERE paidPosts.userIdFK=21643
               AND posts.id = paidPosts.postIdFK)
        OR posts.userIDFK=21643 
     )
) AS row
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: WOW, much better! Thx